# PHP/jQuery: Randomly display single div from loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a loop that contains dynamic and multiple divs. I only need to display single div randomly and when refreshing the page it should change the div dynamically

Like for example PHP

```
for($i= 1; $i<=5; $i++){
     echo'<div class="">
     this is div '.$i.'
     </div>';
}
```

Output will be

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

But i want to only display single div. Other should hide using jquery or php, so whenever i refresh the page it should display any number in the loop randomly

```
//output-->
//this is div 2
```

Comment: `$i = rand(1, 5);` ?

Comment: Calculate a random number `i` from 0 to 4, then use `.eq(i)` to select the DIV with that index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First need to calculate the length of div. Then we hide all other elements and show just the randomly chosen one.

```js
$('.random').hide().eq(Math.floor(Math.random()*$('.random').length)).show();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="random">1</div>
<div class="random">2</div>
<div class="random">3</div>
<div class="random">4</div>
<div class="random">5</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this only with PHP.

```
$array = array("PHP", "CSS", "JavaScript", "jQuery");
$randomItem = $array[array_rand($array)];

<div><?php echo $randomItem ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use both css and php

CSS

```
.Hide_Divs{display: none;}
```

PHP

```
$random = rand(1, 5); // random number between 1 to 5
for($i= 1; $i<=5; $i++){
     $ran = ($i !== $random)? 'Hide_Divs' ? '';
     echo'<div class="'.$ran.'">
     this is div '.$i.'
     </div>';
}
```